# Optaplanner missing a no-args #countDistinct method overload

Tags: optaplanner

I'm just starting with Optaplanner and am trying to recreate the following example from the documentation (https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.37.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#_collecting_countdistinct):

```
private Constraint roomCount(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return factory.from(Talk.class)
            .groupBy(Talk::getRoom, countDistinct())
            .penalize("roomCount",
                    HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                    (room, count) -> ...);
}
```

... But there is no no-args `#countDistinct()` method overload in the [ConstraintCollectors](https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.33.0.Final/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/stream/ConstraintCollectors.html) class. 
There are ony only method overloads that accept a `Function`/`BiFunction`/`TriFunction`/`QuadFunction` respectively.

Am I importing the wrong class, or are there undocumented signature changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good catch, that looks like an oversight in the docs. What you want to do is most easily achieved like so:

```
.groupBy(Talk::getRoom, countDistinct(Function.identity()))
```

The no-argument overload could possibly be added to the API, a syntactic sugar for what I've just shown. I'll [look into it](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-1984) when I find some time.

Wrt. your question about undocumented signature changes - no, that would not happen. The API remains strictly backwards compatible between major versions of OptaPlanner - we actually use [Revapi](https://github.com/revapi/revapi) at build time to enforce that for us. What you're pointing out is most likely just an oversight during doc review.

Thanks for taking the time to point this out.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Worked a charm after a minor correction (`Functions.identity()` -> `Function.identity()`). Great to know that backwards compatibility is enforced and looking forward to scaling the learning curve :)

Comment: Interesting - on my OpenJDK 11, it compiled as suggested. 
I'm not sure I understand how your replacement works, but `talk -> talk` should be equivalent to `Functions.identity()` and compile just fine.